# Adding customers name alongside customer name

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

based on the DB schema I am trying to get for each customer the Id, date, customer name and the customer. Can anyone help?

I am struggling with adding the name of the customer. This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT customer,name,date
from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins to the customers table.  That said, you really need to learn to use *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.  Table aliases are your friend, and arbitrary letters aren't so friendly.

So:

```
SELECT i.Id, i.BillingDate, c.Name as CustomerName,
       cr.Name as ReferredByName
FROM Invoices i LEFT JOIN
     Customers c 
     ON i.CustomerId = c.Id LEFT JOIN
     Customers cr
     ON i.ReferredBy = cr.Id;
```